# maven - choose plugin phase from command line

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, phase

i'm not a maven expert. in my maven2 project i have a couple of report plugins (dependency, tattletale etc). some of them are bound to 'pre-site' phase, some to 'site' phase. this way i have a nice report on my site.

but sometimes, when tests don't pass i need this report to check what's wrong. is there any way to run the same plugins (in correct order) after compile or even after dependency resolution? i just want to skip all the findubs, checkstyle etc that are run at site phase and quickly have this single report to check why my project doesn't compile or why tests fail

i'm looking for something like:

```
mvn -P tattletale-report compile
```

but any other reasonable way will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this plugin in particular but calling goals on the jetty plugin, it works with

```
mvn jetty:run-exploded
```

to give an example. Not knowing the plugin, i'd said

```
mvn tattletale:report
```

should work. Usually the plugin documentation should give you the right goals and commands. But hacking some words in Google, it appears to be a little more complicated.

Comment: so now i have to call `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies org.jboss.tattletale:tattletale-maven:report` and i will need to make this chain longer in near future. i can put this in a batch file. not perfect but works. thanks! i'll still wait for some other posts. maybe it's possible to include it in pom

Comment: You don't have to use the fully qualified names. Each plugin has a prefix that you may use as a shortcut. So, `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` would run the first goal.  For the second, consider adding `org.jboss.tattletale` to `<pluginGroups>` in settings.xml as described in the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html).  Then your full command becomes `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies tattletale:report`.